# How to build a predictive model when the output has a very unequal proportion?

Tags: classification, predictive-models, dataset, unbalanced-classes

I have a dataset that has an column output with two levels, I need to build a predictive model for that column but the output has 97% of records with one level and the other 3% with the other level. This produce a model like this result:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

      Reference
```

Prediction     0     1
         0 15520     0
         1   480     0

```
           Accuracy : 0.97            
             95% CI : (0.9672, 0.9726)
No Information Rate : 1               
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               

              Kappa : 0
```

Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16

```
        Sensitivity : 0.97            
        Specificity :   NA            
     Pos Pred Value :   NA            
     Neg Pred Value :   NA            
         Prevalence : 1.00            
     Detection Rate : 0.97
```

Detection Prevalence : 0.97
      Balanced Accuracy :   NA

```
   'Positive' Class : 0
```

What can I do for improve this?

Comment: You have a problem of unbalanced classes. There are plenty of answer with  this tag (added to your question too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you interested in predicting just the classes, as opposed to probabilities? Then without a very large sample or some strongly predictive features, you can't hope to improve much on a base rate of 97%. Such a prediction problem is very easy and admits little room for improvement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my training dataset has 24000 observations and 75 predictors (35 numeric predictors and 40 logical predictors) My best approach was with glm with a Area under the ROC of 0.51, it's very poor.

Comment: That's a lot of observations, but also a lot of predictors, which could make it hard to find useful predictors. At any rate, if I've answered your question to your satisfaction, don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.

Comment: Finally I obtained a better model applying undersampling for the umbalanced classes and select features using cor() my AUC is now 0.60.